# How do I redirect an .aspx url to a php page?

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

How do I redirect an .aspx url to a php page?
I have links from my old site being domain.com/song.aspx?SongID=1 which I'd like to redirect to a domain.com/song.php?SongID=2 file. Can you someone tell me how to do this?
I'm open to either using htaccess or a plugin. If I use a plugin, I need to be able to have the song.php also get the querystring after song.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Htaccess is probably the best way to go. This rule is pretty general, but should do the trick.

```
RewriteRule ^song\.aspx$ song.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

QSA stands for "Query String Append" and will append the query string from the old URL to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match against the query string and change ID's like in your example:

> domain.com/song.aspx?SongID=1 which I'd like to redirect to a domain.com/song.php?SongID=2

You'll need to setup a list of rewrites for that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SongID=1$
RewriteRule ^/?song\.aspx$ /song.php?SongID=2 [R=301,L]
```